# haskell Pattern Matching: implementing && operator

Tags: haskell

I've seen on my Tutorial that the && operator could be defined as such:

```
True && True = True
_ && _ = False
```

But that the actual implementation on GHC is:

```
True && b = b
_ && _ = False
```

I understand the implementation, but I'm not clear if the first expression doesn't care about the order of the arguments; is that the case?

Because when i try implementing Logical Or in a similar way, i feel it behaves differently:

```
True || b = True
_ || _ = False
```

when i run it:

```
False || True
```

returns False

The correct implementation is actually:

```
False || b = b
_ || _ = True
```

But i feel the previous one should also function correctly...

Comment: What do you mean by "if the first expression doesn't care about the order of the arguments"? Are you asking whether `True && b = b` is equivalent to `b && True = b`? It is not. `True && b` matches if and only if the left operand is `True`.

Comment: Relevant topic: [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short circuiting (&&) in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778919/short-circuiting-in-haskell)

Comment: As a side note: in Boolean algebra there is a well-known principle of De Morgan's duality (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). If you apply it, then you will see that the two equations `True && b = b` and `False || b = b` form a dualistic pair and one follows from the other.

Comment: The GHC implementation allows for errors to remain errors. Your definition would allow something like `True && error "..."` to evaluate to `False`, rather than retaining the error. `False && error "..."` is still `False`, though.

Comment: @chepner As far as I can tell, `True && error "..."` will be an error using both definitions of `&&` presented here or any other correct implementation of `&&` because it's impossible to know what the value of `True && foo` is without knowing the value of `foo`.

Comment: Right, I didn't think that through quite enough.

Comment: thanks everyone, that is a lot to think about

Comment: Looking more carefully to the implementation of && i now see the whole picture. Thanks

Comment: `True && True = True; _ && _ = False` is *identical* to `True && b = b; False && _ = False`. Indeed, if you compile them with optimizations, you get *exactly* the same GHC Core (the compiler's main intermediate language). [Note `bar = foo` in this dump.](https://tio.run/##TYyxDgIhEER7vmKSa@6S4xOutTM29gRlFSIcBCR3ifHbEdfGZmffZGasLg/yvrWXHBDT08W1qLu9Qp4gjakhyeJC8hjkW4RoqicctVsx3mKccdF5Rug8YbOUSXQX51wJOxbsjAftC0F15k@IXvpl@CwsbKr/1He1U6qZxqm1Dw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not clear if the first expression doesn't care about the order of the arguments; is that the case?

The order of operands matters. The pattern `True && b` will match if and only if the *left* operand is `True`. It does not matter whether the right operand is `True`.

> Because when i try implementing Logical Or in a similar way, i feel it behaves differently:
>
> ```
> True || b = True
> _ || _ = False
> ```

This definition will return `True` if and only if the left operand is `True`. Otherwise it will return `False`. This is not a correct implementation of `||` because `||` should return `True` regardless of which operand is `True`.